# Minimum number of coins that makes the given value

Tags: java

I used this code to solve minimum number of coins required problem but can I couldn't understand the logic of using sub_res. Can someone please help me understand that part.

```
 class coin
    {
        // m is size of coins array (number of different coins)
        static int minCoins(int coins[], int m, int V)
        {
           if (V == 0) return 0;
           int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
           for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
           {
             if (coins[i] <= V)
             {
//please help me understand this part
                 int sub_res = minCoins(coins, m, V-coins[i]);
                 if (sub_res != Integer.MAX_VALUE && sub_res + 1 < res)
                    res = sub_res + 1;
             }
           }
           return res;
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
           int coins[] =  {9, 6, 5, 1};
           int m = coins.length;
           int V = 11;
           System.out.println("Minimum coins required is "+ minCoins(coins, m, V) );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `minCoins` inside of `minCoins` itself is a recursive call.  One use of recursive calls is to cut a problem down to a smaller size and keep doing that until it is so small that the result is obvious.  Then the code recurses back down the stack of calls building up the final result as it goes.

In this algorithm, the value `V` that needs to be worked with is being reduced with each call.

The use of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is fundamentally bizarre and you are right to question it.  I think it should be rewritten.  It is being used as a signal that the recursion should stop.  I would determine by walking through versions of the code exactly what happens as the value hits 1 or 0 or less than zero and use something like a conditional test like `if (v <= 0)`. It would be so much clearer to the reader.  Clear programs are much easier to make work, to optimize, and to extend.  Make code clear, then make it work, then make it faster, in that order.  In making code clear you often iron out bugs before you even run the code!

Using `MAX_VALUE` as a signal is problematic because a bug might creep in to modified code that would jigger the value to `MAX_VALUE - 1` or other values.  So the test for inequality `!=` is **brittle** in programming jargon, meaning it is not robust for modified code.

Passing in the length m is unnecessary since the length of the array never changes and thus it can be kept as a static field of the class.  But even that is an optimization (caching).  It could be computed from `coins.length` on entry into `minCoins`.

Note that the `coins` are order from biggest to smallest when the array is initialized.  This is probably necessary to the algorithm (I have not examined it in detail).  It should be documented because that becomes a dependency and at the least it should not be hidden.  A good defensive programming technique would be to perform a quick check for order and then to sort the array at the front of `minCoins` method, if they are not in decreasing order.

Why program defensively?  Because code should always be suspicious of user input and be robust for possible re-use.

Answer (score 0):

The statement wants to say: if the coin is less than the total sum value, then we will include the coin and decrease the total sum `V-coins[i]`. Since we need to make sum as `V` so coins larger than it will not be included.